# Is it possible to use fixtures from other apps in django's tests?

Tags: django, testing, fixtures

I have 2 apps, members and resources. resources depends on members. Is it possible to use test fixtures from the members app in my tests for the resources app?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently yes, any fixture can be loaded from any app as if it was in the same app, so be wary of what you name your fixtures. :/

Answer (score 7):

For example, if you have two apps, one named for "App1" and the other named "App2", and the structure of your project is something like this:

```
myproject/
----APP1/
--------models/
------------app_1_model.py
--------tests/
------------test_app1.py
--------fixtures/
------------fixture_app1_number_1.json
------------fixture_app1_number_2.json
----APP2/
--------models/
------------app_2_model.py
--------tests/
------------test_app2.py
--------fixtures/
------------fixture_app2_number_1.json
------------fixture_app2_number_2.json
------------fixture_app2_number_3.json
```

this is a imaginary scenario, and you want to write test script for "APP2" but your test script may need the data from "APP1", in other words you need the fixtures in "APP1"

```
from APP1.models.app_1_model import *
class TestApp2(TestCase):
   fixtures = ['fixture_app2_number_1','fixture_app2_number_2','fixture_app2_number_3','fixture_app1_number_1']
   def test_function_one(self):
     pass
```

as you saw, just write the fixture name of "APP1" in the fixtures list, very intelligent and easy.